# Trying to combine multiple onEdit functions

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to combine multiple onEdit functions and as a beginner am struggling to get it to work. Functions 2 to 5 work well on their own, it is when I have added the new `myFunction 1(e)` it has stopped working and returns an error message of

> TypeError: Cannot Read property 'value' of undefined

and refers to the two lines marked in bold type below.

Ultimately I was aiming to get a timestamp for each checkbox that evaluates to true in a new column to the right of the checkbox (there are 4 columns with checkboxes on my sheet).

Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
function onEdit(e){
 **myFunction1(e);**
 myFunction2(e);
 myFunction3(e);
 myFunction4(e);
 myFunction5(e);
}
```

```js
function myFunction1(e){
  // KP - this function returns a timestamp to the right of a checkbox with a value of true
**if(e.value!="TRUE") return;**
   e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart+1).setValue(new Date());
}
```

```js
function myFunction2(e){
 // KP - this function autosorts the due date column when a date is changed or added
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if (sheet.getName() == 'Job List - Input') {
 var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
 var columnToSortBy = 5;
 var tableRange = "A5:U"; // What to sort
 // column A = 1, B = 2, etc…
 if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
   var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
   range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
 }
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting this error only when running onEdit() from the script editor or do you also get the error if you edit the sheet?

Comment: If you're trying to run this from the script editor then that won't work because you are not providing the event object.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The error message is from the script editor. When editing the sheet, none of the functions work. It looks like I am missing something about defining the event object but can't work out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

By running that code from the Apps Script editor you are expected to receive an error. I see that the code is designed to manage the event object generated by a trigger, but running it from the IDE won't provide the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). You should run this script from a triggering event. Since this works with `onEdit()`, you should edit the bundled Sheet to start the code. Please ask me to clarify my point if you need so.

Comment: Thanks Jaques-Guzel. I figured out that if I cut out that part of the script, saved the file then pasted it back again without running it from the editor then it all works fine.